# DevTools failed to parse SourceMap

Tags: javascript, webpack, google-chrome-devtools, webpack-2

I am trying to get my Webpack project to have a source map file.

I finally got the settings right so that it would do that, but now I am getting this error:

> DevTools failed to parse SourceMap: http://MyServer/MyApp/bundle.js.map

I go to the URL it states and I find a json file with these properties:

- *version*  - Set to 3
- *sources*  - very long array of strings that seem to be webpack paths to my files.
- *names*    - very long array of strings that seem to be random variables and functions.
- *mappings* - very long string of seemingly random capitol letters and commas.
- *file*     - set to bundle.js
- *sourcesContent*  - Very Very long array of strings (over 10 million chars). All my source code.
- *sourceRoot* - set to empty string

It all seems to be valid json.  Unfortunally Chrome gives no reason why it failed to parse the source map.

**Is there a way to get Chrome to say why it failed parsing the source map?**

**Or, failing that, does anyone know why my source map would fail?**  (My code is way too large to post, but here are my [webpack.config.js](https://gist.github.com/Vaccano/eec28a554ddaaab3f631d15d8d05e988#file-webpack-config-js) and my [package.json](https://gist.github.com/Vaccano/eec28a554ddaaab3f631d15d8d05e988#file-package-json) files.)

NOTES:

- I have tried this with webpack 2.2.1, webpack 2.3.2 and webpack 2.6.1.
- Source maps work fine in IE 11 and Firefox.
- If I inline my source maps, then they work fine in Chrome DevTools, but then my bundle.js goes from 3 MB (already too big) to 16 MB (WAY too big).
- I have set "Enable JavaScript Source Maps" in settings (and the CSS one too).
- I tried using Chrome Canary, but it had the same issue.
- I am hosting in IIS.

Comment: It seems this is a problem with chrome, had the same problem but never found an answer. The closest I got was to set devtool: 'source-map' and manually make sure the working files are added in the sources tab.

Comment: ** the problem being that chrome can't read large sourcemaps

Comment: Here is a possible reason - a Chrome bug: https://superuser.com/a/1526134/286913

Answer (score 27):

It is not an answer to this question, but i believe my answer can help some people.

This is due to the settings of chrome, for example in FF this error warnings not happens.
To fix it go to Developer Tools Settings of Chrome, and uncheck:

1. "Enable JavaScript source maps"
2. "Enable CSS source maps"

Then refresh Chrome.

In order to debug `js` and `scss` minified files, this tells the compiler where the source file is actually mapped.

Using last versions of Webpack source-map work well, 
I tried to reproduce this bug, but without possibility to run a project, i can't see what a problem of author of a question.

This warning happening for example using angular, and `sourceMap` should be set `true` in `angular.json`, or other way  if you don't use source-map'ing' and you don't want see this warning disable it in browser following my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the solution but do you know why this fixes the warning?

Comment: To debug js and scss  minified files, this tells compiler where is source file actually mapped.

Comment: Thank you.  This is what did it for me as well (just had to remember how to get to Developer Tool Settings in Chrome).

View > Developer > Developer Tools (or ⌥ ⌘I)

Comment: This only works if you don't use source maps. It's hardly a fix.

Comment: @ZachSmith Using last versions of Webpack source-map work well, this warning happing for example using angular, and "sourceMap" should be set "true" in angular.json, or other way to disable it in browser if you don't use source-map'ing'

Comment: This isn't an answer. It's like asking why your car is smoking and being told to stop driving your car. Yes, not driving my car stops the car from smoking.

Comment: @toxaq depends on each person’s personal search, in many cases this is the answer to a slightly different question, but with the same wording

Comment: @ArthurTsidkilov the OP wants source maps, your answers turns off the processing of them. If there is an error with them, fix the error, don't hide it.

Comment: @toxaq  the question written 2 years ago, in this forms it is not relevant any more, but some people need to hide sourceMap and how to enable sourceMap for example in angular i answered here. And i see there are people who need it.

Comment: @ArthurTsidkilov unfortunately StackOverflow ranks very highly in Google so your "solution" of not driving your car if the engine is running rough turns up very highly for people searching for rough running engines. Justify it to yourself all you like, this isn't an answer to the problem.

Comment: @toxaq you are right, i don't answer a question but for some people searching this it is an answer for the problem they search to solve, do you want i remove it from here, i don't really  understand what you want from me? )))

Comment: @ArthurTsidkilov The comment you've added at the start of your answer is a good improvement. I would just have something like "This isn't a solution to the problem but if you just need the sourcemap errors to go away then you can disable sourcemap processing using the following instructions". As long as newbies can turn up and realise that there are downstream consequences to their actions they can make an informed choice.

Comment: @toxaq nice)  You are right, better to give more descriptions. I believe it is not so important to stay on it to much. Enough liki it is. If you want you can add other answer more complete.

Answer (score 10):

From experience, I wouldn't expect a client to tell you why it couldn't parse a SourceMap (although that would be nice). I have run into issues with some tools being unable to parse large source maps (probably memory constraints), and given your large asset size, I would look at that first.

Webpack supports several different values for the `devtool` config field, and some of them are less faithful than the default. Have you tried, for example, `'cheap-module-source-map'`? Getting line numbers only (no columns) is a fine trade off for a usable source map IMO.

But it will probably serve you better to reduce the asset size. Webpack's [code splitting](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/) and 'chunk' management options make it pretty straightforward to split your code into multiple files that are loaded async at runtime. In this case you would have two or more JS files, and each would have its own source map, so the browser will no longer choke trying to process one big file.

Answer (score 5):

In my case, I had to disable **Adblock** to get rid of the error.

Comment: I had to disable LastPass extension

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that some **chrome extensions** are messing with DevTools.

Perhaps, you could try disabling the ones you do not need for your particular app and see if that "fixes" the problem.

Above is the approach that worked for me but I'm not really sure why it does.

Comment: its the LastPass application for me